# Alfresco 5.1 CE: Versioning on CIFS shares does not work as expected

Tags: alfresco

we have setup versioning as described in the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/versionable-make.html). Additionally we have added

```
version.store.enableAutoVersioning=true
```

to the *alfresco-global.properties* file and restarted Alfresco.
But nevertheless, all files created on the cifs share lack the aspect *cm:versionable*.
But when we update one of the files via the webinterface, this aspect is added to this file and all further changes to the file via the cifs share are recorded in the document history.

So the question is, where can we define, that objects created on a cifs share automatically get the required aspect *cm:versionable*?

Thanks for any hints and suggestions in advance,

Stefan

Answer (score 2):

We were able to solve it: The documentation just says "Add a Spring context file to $TOMCAT_HOME/shared/classes/alfresco/extension ...", but the point is, that his configuration file has to end on "-context.xml" (we're now using contentModel-context.xml) otherwise Tomcat will not find and read the file.

Comment: Kudos for comming back to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative in Alfresco Community 5.2 (201704) you could create a Rule on the Sites folder that adds the cm:versionable aspect to all new content.

Im not sure of the performance implications of this approach